# Issue when simulating c code in MPLAB

Tags: c, simulation

I have the following issue when simulating my code in MPLAB v8.56 - the program always starts in one of the brackets of the code, not in the beginning of it as it should be. Is this normal? Does it have repercussions when I burn the code into the pic?

This is the code:

```
#include <p18f4550.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include "configuracion.h"


void SECUENCIA_1();
void SECUENCIA_2();
void SECUENCIA_3();
void SECUENCIA_4();
void SECUENCIA_5();
void SECUENCIA_6();
void SECUENCIA_ERROR();
void SALIDA_OK();
void SECUENCIA_DEFAULT(); 
int i;
unsigned char COMBINACION;

void main(void) {


UCONbits.USBEN = 0;
UCFGbits.UTRDIS = 1;



ADCON0 = 0x00; 
ADCON1 = 0x0F; 
TRISA  = 0x00;
PORTA  = 0x00;
TRISB  = 0xFF;
PORTB  = 0x00;
TRISC  = 0xF0;
PORTC  = 0x00;
TRISD  = 0xF8;
PORTD  = 0x00;
TRISE  = 0x00;
PORTE  = 0x00;



COMBINACION = 0x00;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTCbits.RC5);
COMBINACION = COMBINACION << 1;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTCbits.RC4);
COMBINACION = COMBINACION << 1;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTDbits.RD3);



switch (COMBINACION)
    {
    case 0x0: SECUENCIA_DEFAULT(); break;
    case 0x1: SECUENCIA_1(); break;
    case 0x2: SECUENCIA_2(); break;
    case 0x3: SECUENCIA_3(); break;
    case 0x4: SECUENCIA_4(); break;
    case 0x5: SECUENCIA_5(); break;
    case 0x6: SECUENCIA_6(); break;
    default:SECUENCIA_DEFAULT();
    }

}

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /////////////////INICIO DE LA SECUENCIA 1////////////
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 void SECUENCIA_1()
 {
 PORTA = 0b000001;
 if (PORTAbits.RA0 == PORTBbits.RB7) PORTA = 0b000010;  
else SECUENCIA_ERROR(); 
 if (PORTAbits.RA1 == PORTBbits.RB6) PORTA = 0b000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTAbits.RA2 == PORTBbits.RB5) PORTA = 0b001000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTAbits.RA3 == PORTBbits.RB4) PORTA = 0b010000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTAbits.RA4 == PORTBbits.RB3) PORTA = 0b100000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTAbits.RA5 == PORTBbits.RB2) PORTE = 0b001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTEbits.RE0 == PORTBbits.RB1) PORTE = 0b010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTEbits.RE1 == PORTBbits.RB0) PORTE = 0b100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTEbits.RE2 == PORTDbits.RD7) PORTC = 0b00000001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTCbits.RC0 == PORTDbits.RD6) PORTC = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTCbits.RC1 == PORTDbits.RD5) PORTC = 0b00000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTCbits.RC2 == PORTDbits.RD4)  PORTD = 0b00000001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTDbits.RD0 == PORTCbits.RC7)  PORTD = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 if (PORTDbits.RD1 == PORTCbits.RC6)  SALIDA_OK();
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 }




//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////INICIO DE LA SECUENCIA 2////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void SECUENCIA_2()
{
PORTA = 0b000001;
if (PORTAbits.RA0 == PORTBbits.RB7) PORTA = 0b000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA1 == PORTBbits.RB6) PORTA = 0b000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA2 == PORTBbits.RB5) PORTA = 0b001000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA3 == PORTBbits.RB4) PORTA = 0b010000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA4 == PORTBbits.RB3) PORTA = 0b100000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA5 == PORTBbits.RB2) PORTE = 0b001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTEbits.RE0 == PORTBbits.RB1) PORTE = 0b010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTEbits.RE1 == PORTBbits.RB0) PORTE = 0b100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTEbits.RE2 == PORTDbits.RD7) PORTC = 0b00000001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC0 == PORTDbits.RD6) SALIDA_OK();
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
}





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////INICIO DE LA SECUENCIA 3////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void SECUENCIA_3()
{
PORTC = 0b00000001;
if (PORTCbits.RC0 == PORTBbits.RB7) PORTC = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC1 == PORTBbits.RB6) PORTC = 0b00000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC2 == PORTBbits.RB5) PORTD = 0b00000001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTDbits.RD0 == PORTBbits.RB4) PORTD = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTDbits.RD1 == PORTBbits.RB3) SALIDA_OK();
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
}




//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////INICIO DE LA SECUENCIA 4////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void SECUENCIA_4()
{
PORTC = 0b00000001;
if (PORTCbits.RC0 == PORTBbits.RB7) PORTC = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC1 == PORTBbits.RB6) PORTC = 0b00000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC2 == PORTBbits.RB5) SALIDA_OK();
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
}




//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////INICIO DE LA SECUENCIA 5////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void SECUENCIA_5()
{
PORTD = 0b00000001;
if (PORTDbits.RD0 == PORTBbits.RB7) PORTD = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTDbits.RD1 == PORTBbits.RB6) SALIDA_OK();
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////INICIO DE LA SECUENCIA 6////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void SECUENCIA_6()
{
PORTA = 0b000001;
if (PORTAbits.RA0 == PORTCbits.RC6) PORTA = 0b000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA1 == PORTCbits.RC7) PORTA = 0b000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA2 == PORTDbits.RD4) PORTA = 0b001000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA3 == PORTDbits.RD5) PORTA = 0b010000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA4 == PORTDbits.RD6) PORTA = 0b100000;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTAbits.RA5 == PORTDbits.RD7) PORTE = 0b001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTEbits.RE0 == PORTBbits.RB0) PORTE = 0b010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTEbits.RE1 == PORTBbits.RB1) PORTE = 0b100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTEbits.RE2 == PORTBbits.RB2) PORTC = 0b00000001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC0 == PORTBbits.RB3) PORTC = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC1 == PORTBbits.RB4) PORTC = 0b00000100;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTCbits.RC2 == PORTBbits.RB5) PORTD = 0b00000001;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTDbits.RD0 == PORTBbits.RB6) PORTD = 0b00000010;
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
if (PORTDbits.RD1 == PORTBbits.RB7) SALIDA_OK();
else SECUENCIA_ERROR();
}





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////SALIDAS DE LAS SECUENCIAS////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void SALIDA_OK()
{
for(;;)
{
 PORTDbits.RD2 = 1;
 Delay10KTCYx(200);
}

 }

void SECUENCIA_ERROR()
{
 i = 0;
 for (i=0;i<=1000;i++)
 {
 PORTDbits.RD2 ^=1;
 Delay1KTCYx(50);
 }

}

void SECUENCIA_DEFAULT()
{
 i = 0;
 for (i=0;i<=10;i++)
 {
 PORTDbits.RD2 ^=1;
 Delay10KTCYx(100);

 }
}
```

The program starts on the `void SECUENCIA_OK()` end bracket

Comment: There is no SECUENCIA_OK in the code you pasted.

Comment: what do you mean one of the brackets? There are no brackets in the code you posted

Comment: Do you mean `SALIDA_OK`?

Comment: @SteveCox Many people use _brackets_ to refer to any grouping punctuation: square brackets, parentheses, angle brackets, and curly braces.

Comment: i just want to help. its highly ambiguous where the program is starting. is it the void function SALIDA_OK()?

Comment: ok sorry, was my mistake, it starts at the curly brace that closes the void function SALIDA_OK()